# how to create marker's bubble in googleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new in android and I am want tap on marker and bubble show up as shown [here](http://www.actionshrimp.com/2011/05/speech-bubble-popups-containing-a-view-for-android-mapview/). I don't know how to use this, is there any other example for that so I can use it or learn it how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this github : [Jeff Gilfelt Github - android-mapview-balloon](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons).

It's exactly what you need. If you don't want to use it directly, the source code is pretty simple.

I hope you already have tried [Hello MapView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) and read a little bit of [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html) :)

You could add to your question the code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

present the code what have you tried so far...

The general idea is to place markers(Drawables) on the map first...while placing them add onclicklistener to them and implementing the view for the onclick listener then...